# Android Development - using a variable to open raw or asset file

Tags: android, variables, assets

I'm a very new user to Android development.
I've been building a small flash card app to help kids read and the ultimate task I am trying to accomplish is read a text file's contents, split it into an array, then display one of those words on the screen.  Relatively simple.

The problem I am having is trying to use a variable to open a .txt file in either the raw or assets folder.  I have researched and been directed to many examples and I guess I'm simply not understanding what to do here.

Below is various attempts I have put into this over the last 12 hours.  I could really use some lamens term help and direction here.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
// variable for files  in 'raw' directory
Integer[] fileList = { R.raw.animals, R.raw.colors, R.raw.fullwords, R.raw.numbers, R.raw.shapes };



// this is the portion that picks the word and plays the associated audio file
try {
       fileStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fullwords);
       fileLen = fileStream.available();

       // Read the entire resource into a local byte buffer.
       byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[fileLen];
       fileStream.read(fileBuffer);
       fileStream.close();

       // build text file contents to an array
       displayText = new String(fileBuffer);
       listArray = displayText.split(",");

       // pick a random number
       maxNumber = listArray.length;
       randomNo = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((maxNumber - 0) + 1));

       // post to textView of 'textofWord'
       textofWord.setText("");

       // listArray[randomNo]
       textofWord.setText(listArray[randomNo]);

       // create audio file name
       audioFileName = listArray[randomNo] + ".mp3";
       audioFileLocation = "/raw/" + listArray[randomNo];

       // launch the audio file - using SoundPool so it can be clicked multiple times - quickly if they like :)
       wordSound = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

       // replace "grenade" with listArray[randomNo] when the audio files are made
       int sound_id = this.getResources().getIdentifier("grenade", "raw", this.getPackageName());
       audioWord = wordSound.load(this, sound_id, 1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
          // exception handling
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have also tried....

```
fileStream = getResources().openRawResource(fileList[trigger]);
fileLen = fileStream.available();
```

fileList being an int array
trigger being an int that is created in an if else if design

...as well as trying....

```
int id = this.getResources().getIdentifier(value, "raw", this.getPackageName());
fileStream = getResources().openRawResource(id);
fileLen = fileStream.available();
```

...this will allow the right activity to load, but the text that appears in the textview is just "0"

```
String FILENAME = value + ".txt";
String collected = null;
FileInputStream fis = null;

// this is the portion that picks the word and plays the associated audio file
try {
fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
while (fis.read(dataArray) != -1) {
collected = new String(dataArray);
}

       // build text file contents to an array
       // displayText = new String(fileBuffer);
       listArray = collected.split(",");

       // pick a random number
       maxNumber = listArray.length;
       randomNo = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((maxNumber - 0) + 1));

       // post to textView of 'textofWord'
       textofWord.setText("");

       // listArray[randomNo]
       textofWord.setText(listArray[randomNo]);﻿
```

I even tried rearranging the try catch framework and...nothing.  I am beginning to feel that it is utterly impossible to load a file based on a variable....

```
String FILENAME = value + ".txt";
String collected = null;
FileInputStream fis = null;

// this is the portion that picks the word and plays the associated audio file
try {
fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
while (fis.read(dataArray) != -1) {
collected = new String(dataArray);
}

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {
          // exception handling
        e.printStackTrace();

        }   finally {
        try {
        fis.close();

           // build text file contents to an array
           // displayText = new String(fileBuffer);
           listArray = collected.split(",");

           // pick a random number
           maxNumber = listArray.length;
           randomNo = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((maxNumber - 0) + 1));

           // post to textView of 'textofWord'
           textofWord.setText("");

           // listArray[randomNo]
           textofWord.setText(collected);

           // create audio file name
           audioFileName = listArray[randomNo] + ".mp3";
           audioFileLocation = "/raw/" + listArray[randomNo];

           // launch the audio file - using SoundPool so it can be clicked multiple times -             quickly if they like :)
           wordSound = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

           // replace "grenade" with listArray[randomNo] when the audio files are made
           int sound_id = this.getResources().getIdentifier("grenade", "raw", this.getPackageName());
           audioWord = wordSound.load(this, sound_id, 1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }﻿
```

I'm really sorry for blasting this out there, but I'm genuinely lost on how to use a variable to load a file name.
I've used other programming languages such as php, sql, some c++, etc and using a variable to call a file is extremely simple.

What am I missing?
What am I not understanding in this process?

Any direction or information to help me better understand this would be eternally appreciated.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: You say it 'does not work' - what do you mean by this? Does the activity crash on loading? If that's happening, could you post the stack trace that's being output in Logcat? Also, I assume 'value' is the file name as a String and 'trigger' is an index into the fileList array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following code and it works for me. Run this code on your application with your specific file id and see if it gets the data or not -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        //store the ids into array, put your corresponding raw file ids
        int[] resources = {R.raw.hel};
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resources[0]);
        Log.d("demo" , "available bytes = " + is.available());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        int readCount = is.read(buffer);
        Log.d("demo", "Read data = "+new String(buffer, 0, readCount));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the exact format of resources[0], or in my case fileList[0]; absolutely does work. 

However, I need to be able to do fileList[variable] instead of an exact number.

Is that possible?

Comment: I think I found the issue.  I'm using the log.d notation you demonstrated above and found that my variable for the fileList is turning up NULL for some reason.  Researching now and will notate the findings.

Comment: I have narrowed down my problem to passing the variable from 1 activity to another...

  String extras = getIntent().getExtras().getString("triggerWord");
   Log.d("triggerWords", "triggerWords = " + extras);
      
  if (extras == "Basic Words") {
   Log.d("ifcheck", "Success");
  }

This, however, does not fire the 'ifcheck' log statement.
I do not know why, however.  Any advice as to what I'm doing wrong in moving my variable from 1 activity to another?

Comment: VICTORY!!!
Ok so I will admit stupidity and noobness.
== doesn't work in java so the correct syntax is variable.equals("string") in my if statement.

however, imranhasanhira, thank you greatly!  you have helped a lot. 
I think I marked your answer as ... complete or correct?  Thank you for the help!